# How to let my VBA code skip the Application.Intersect function when there are no cells for the filter criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I let my my code skip the `Application.Intersect` function when there are no data points for the filter criteria? The error occurs at line 3 and 4 stating:
[image: Error]

I tried the (on line 3):
`If IsError(Intersect(filterRange, filterRange.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = False Then`

But it does not work. 
I also tried: 
`If Not IsError(Intersect(filterRange, filterRange.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) Then`

```
Set filterRange = Worksheets("JO_Pickups (Test)").Range("$A$1:$E$" & Total_rows_JOPickTest) 'filter for less computations
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=JO_id(i)
If IsError(Intersect(filterRange, filterRange.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = False Then
    Set filteredRange = Intersect(filterRange, filterRange.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'remove headers
    If Not filteredRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each Area In filteredRange.Areas
            Worksheets("JO_Pickups (Test)").Range(Area.Address).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Help Worksheet").Cells(2, 1)
        Next Area
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trap a runtime error using IsError(), so you need something like:

```
Dim visRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set visRng = filterRange.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0

If Not visRng is Nothing Then
    'do stuff...
End If
```

Comment: What does `On Error Goto 0` mean though? Also what if there was no error until a bit somewhere down the line and it is not  involved with the `filterRange.Offset(1,0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` line of code, will it also bypass the next error?

Comment: `On Error Goto 0` cancels the `On Error Resume Next` - it's good practise to cancel that as soon as your "anticipated" error has been bypassed - it's not intended for general-purpose error handling.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense